# Expanding a snippet within a snippet (vim or sublime)

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, code-snippets

I'm trying to improve my work flow a little bit and I'm trying to accomplish something but don't really know where to start.

I'm a huge fan of snippets, I've been customizing lots of my own, and it really helps me write code much faster, and actually avoid errors as well.

However, I'd like to be able to expand a snippet while I'm still tabbing through a current snippet.

Any idea what I might be able to do? Is there a version of snippets for vim that does this? Is there a key binding I can put into sublime that might help?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about `snipmate` but you definitely can do that with [Ultisnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715).

Comment: With the original _snipMate_, this is **NOT** possible.